# RegularExpression - Regexp to find longest unique non overlapping cycles in a string

Tags: regex, string, language-agnostic, recurrence, substring

I have a string -> 'abcabcabclslslsokjokjokj'
I need to find an algorithm which is able to identify all recurrences(Or at least one longest unique)

I have found `(\w+?)\1+` (Works for Ruby) it works like charm for single recurrence.

```
'abcabcabcabc' #=> 'abc'
```

But fails for `'ababcababcababcababcababcababc'`, where expected result is `ababc` but comes out to be `ab`

Where am I wrong, and what is the correct way to find:-

1. First unique cyclic pattern (`ababcababcababcjkjkjkjk` => `ababc`)
   2(Bonus). All unique non-overlapping cyclic repititions in a string, (`ababcababcababcabhabhabhlklklk` => `ababc`, `abh`, `lk`)

Comment: Use a greedy quantifier: [`(\w+)\1+`](https://regex101.com/r/ycPW8K/2)

Comment: Why did you use the lazy quantifier in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

[Use this regex](https://regex101.com/r/jJsjoG/2) to find all repeated subpatterns in the string.

```
(?=(\w+)\1)
```

You will then need some extra code to check all matching subgroups for the longest one.

**Explanation:**

More than a simple regex is needed, because the first repeated pattern encountered will "gobble up" the part of the string that matches.  And that part of the string can no longer be used for other potential matches.  Consider this example:

```
abcabccabc
```

The longest repeated pattern is `cabc`, but this would not be found by a simple regex like `(\w+)\1`, because it would match `abcabc` and then no longer look in that part of the string.

A positive look-ahead `(?=...)`, which does not consume the string when it matches, is used to find the longest potential repeating pattern, and store that in a capture group.  This will be checked starting at each character in the string.

Comment: Yeah, I also tried this regex for overlapping matches. Still, it requires something other than regex. However, the dot is not even necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for the problem in javascript without Regular Expression (Regex)

```
const longestString = str => {
  obj = {};
  longest = [];
  current = [];
  for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    if (obj[str[i]] === undefined) {
      obj[str[i]] = 1;
      current.push(str[i]);
    } else {
      if (current.length > longest.length) {
        longest = [...current];
        current = [];
        obj = {};
        obj[str[i]] = 1;
        current.push(str[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return longest.join('');
}

console.log(longestString('ababcababcababcababcababcababc'));
```

#### Output

```
abc
```